# How do I trigger the Sitemap Provider in DNN to create a new sitemap?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have a custom Sitemap Provider on one of my modules and would like to trigger DNN to create a new sitemap.

Normally you can do this by going to www.dnndev.me/sitemap.aspx, but when I debug it, it only executed once, so is there a Scheduler I need to activate or a Cache I need to clear?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sitemap cache can be cleared when you go to SEO > Sitemap Settings and Clicking on the Clear Cache button.

Comment: After deleting the cache, navigate to www.yourwebsite.com/sitemap.aspx and it will hit the debug breakpoint on your sitemap.cs file in your module.